# question on n-th root coverings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety and $D \subset X$ an effective divisor. Assume that there is a line bundle $L$ such that $L^n=\mathcal{O}(D)$ for some integer $d \geq 2$.

Suppose $s \in H^0(X, L^n)$ is a non-zero section.

To these data it is associated a degree $n$ cyclic cover $Y \to X$ ramified at $D$. A possible construction is the following: letting $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{L}^d$ denote the total spaces of the line bundles $L$ and $L^d$, there is a map $\eta: \mathbf{L} \to \mathbf{L}^d$. The section $s \in H^0(X, L^n)$ gives a geometric section $s: X \to \mathbf{L}^d$ and one can define $Y$ as the normalization of $\eta^{-1}(s(X))$ together with the natural map to $X$.

**Question**: how this construction depends on $s$? I mean, if I am given $X$, $D$ and $L$ with the property that $L^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(D)$, is it unique? Or do I have to fix an isomorphism? And if I fix such an isomorphism, does it depend on the choice of $s$?

Comment: If you want your cyclic cover to be ramified at $D$, then $s$ should depend on $D$. In your construction, it only depends on the linear equivalence class of $D$. So you are obtaining a cyclic cover which is ramified over some divisor which is linearly equivalent to $D$, not necessary $D$ itself. To get it ramified over $D$, you need to choose $s$ so that its support is exactly $D$. There is a unique choice of such section, up to scalar multiplication.

Comment: Oh, thanks! So that's the main point: I have to choose $s$ with zero divisor $D$ if I want the cyclic cover to be ramified at D, right? Can you say why there is a unique choice up to scalars?

Comment: In general, any two choices of section vanishing on a divisor differ by an invertible function. But $X$ is projective, hence such a function is a non-zero constant.